# No module named 'numpy' error in tensorflow images retraining

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, docker

I am recently following a tutorial of tensor flow images classification (Tensor flow for poets). Whenever I try to retrain my images data-set I get following exception:

[image: Please See Attached Screenshot]

I have checked my `Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages` folder and found a folder named 'numpy' there. Moreover, when I tried to import numpy in Python it was successfully imported.

The version of my Python is **3.5.2**. And numpy is found at `C:\\Users\\ummara.anjum\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py`.

Comment: seems like the docker image you are running does not contain the numpy python module. Be sure to rebuild that image with the correct python modules

Comment: When presenting textual data to your audience, please use a text format. Images are not compatible with screen-readers, clipboards or search engines, and as a result it is harder for readers to help you. Please delete that image by editing your post, and paste in the same data as text, and then use the formatting tool provided to make it presentable. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried to import numpy in python it was successfully imported.

Did you do this in cmd prompt?
Have you tried to do it in the prompt/shell you showed in the screenshot?

Make sure python & numpy is available in the shell you are using. 
Check if you need to alias, add path or activate environment to use the proper python.

Comment: I was using cmd to import numpy. yes now going to do this in docker container.